# Why is this grouping operator + function immediately invoked

Tags: javascript, iife

I'am studying the behaviour of Immediatly Invoked Function Expressions (IIFE) and while doing that I encounterd the following situation.

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
})

(function () {
    document.write("foo");
}());
```

I thought that the first is just a grouping operator with a function expression inside without calling it. The second is a grouping operator as well with a function expression but now with the call of that function.

What I find strange is that both are invoked, why is that?

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
})

var x = 1;

(function () {
    document.write("foo");
}());
```

When I break the two by inserting a variable declaration in between, it's just writes foo. This is what I expected.

Comment: Tip: use http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you forgot the semicolon after the first function expression:

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
});
```

Otherwise the second "grouping operator" is interpreted as a function call. So this:

```
(function a() {
    ...
})

(function b() {
    ...
}());
```

is basically the same as:

```
function b() {
    ...
}

(function a() {
    ...
})(b());
```

Reordering makes it a bit easier to see. Remember that white space characters have no meaning in JavaScript and are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

As Felix Kling correctly noted: the missing semicolon causes the parentheses around the second IIFE to be interpreted as a *function call* rather than just grouping the function expression. It becomes much more clear without the newlines:

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
})(function () {
    document.write("foo");
}());
```

Or with some realignment:

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
})(
    function () {
        document.write("foo");
    }()
);
```

The first function expression is called with the result of the second function expression as its first and only argument. You should also note that `foobar` is written rather than `barfoo`, as the second function is called first and its result is passed as an argument to the first function.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a IIFE also like that: `(function () {})()`

By omitting the semicolon, your first codesnippet actually calls the first function with the second IIFE handed over as parameter for the first.

```
                    executing as parameter for the first IIFE
                                               \/ 
(function () {document.write("bar");})( (function () {document.write("foo");}());)
```

which first prints `foo` and then `bar` unlike:

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
})();

(function () {
    document.write("foo");
}());
```

which prints `barfoo` or

```
(function () {
    document.write("bar");
});

(function () {
    document.write("foo");
}());
```

where the first now is solely considered as grouping operator.