# Immediately invoked function expression throws "object is not a function"

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm defining various modules in a `Javascript` file:

```
var module = {/* ... */}

(function(){
    console.log('Invoked');
})()
```

However the `IIFE` throws an error:

**> TypeError: object is not a function**

I tried just copy and pasting the `IIFE` code and there is no issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this grouping operator + function immediatly invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810951/why-is-this-grouping-operator-function-immediatly-invoked)

Comment: You should always use semicolons after your statements - https://stackoverflow.com/a/444082/1766230

Comment: Related: [`TypeError`: `console.log(…)` is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31013221/4642212).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The module definition needs a semicolon at the end of the declaration:

```
var module = {/* ... */}; // <======= Semicolon!

(function(){
    console.log('Invoked');
})()
```

Without it Javascript is trying to call the object:

```
var module = {/* ... */}(function(){console.log('Invoked');})()
```

Or shortened:

```
var module = {/* ... */}()
```

You'd get the same problem when trying to writing two IIFEs next to each other:

```
(function(){})()
(function(){})()
```

This doesn't work because a single function declaration returns `undefined`:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function