# TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm really confused how I can get console.log is not a function on line 1091. If I remove the closure below, line 1091 doesn't complain such error. Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
$scope.columnNameChanged = function (tableColumn) {
    setDirtyColumn(tableColumn);
    //propagate changes to the key fields
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.tableIndexes.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0; j < $scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName.length; ++j) {
            if ($scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName[j] === tableColumn.previousName) {
                console.log('xxx', $scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName[j])
                (function (i, j) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        console.log($scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName[j])
                        $scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName[j] = tableColumn.name.toUpperCase();
                        console.log($scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName[j])
                    });
                })(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry the picture seems to be resized to be too small. I'm trying figure out how to make it show the original size.

Comment: Please don't use pictures for showing your code and errors, it's bad practice.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

### Solution

Simply put a semicolon (`;`) after `console.log(`…`)`.

---

### Explanation

The error is easily reproducible like this:

```js
console.log()
(function(){})
```

It’s trying to pass `function(){}` as an argument to the *return value* of `console.log()` which itself is not a function but actually `undefined` (check `typeof console.log();`). This is because JavaScript interprets this as `console.log()(function(){})`. **`console.log`** however *is* a function.

If you didn’t have the `console` object you’d see

> ReferenceError: console is not defined

If you had the `console` object but not the `log` method you’d see

> TypeError: console.log is not a function

What you have, however, is

> TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function

Note the `(...)` after the function name. With those it’s referring to the return value of the function.

The line break [doesn’t separate these two expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51816366/4642212) as separate statements because of JavaScript’s [rules for automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/4642212).

---

### Respect the `;`

All these code snippets result in all sorts of unexpected errors if no semicolons are present:

```js
console.log() // As covered before
() // TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function
```

```js
console.log() // Accessing property 0 of property 1 of the return value…
[1][0] // TypeError: console.log(...) is undefined
```

```js
console.log() // Like undefined-3
-3 // NaN
```

```js
let a, b;
const array = Array.from({ length: 2 })

// Now, let’s use destructuring:
[a, b] = array; // ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'array' before initialization
```

```js
let a, b;
const array = Array.from({ length: 2 }).fill(1),
  array2 = Array.from({ length: 2 })

// Now, let’s use destructuring. Attempt to get the two 1’s from `array` as `a` and `b`:
[a, b] = array;
console.log(a, b); // undefined undefined
```

---

### Another Example

You see the `(...)` oftentimes with the use of chained methods or chained property accessors:

```
string.match(/someRegEx/)[0]
```

If that RegEx isn’t found, the method will return `null` and the property accessor on `null` will cause a `TypeError: string.match(...) is null` — the *return value* is `null`. In the case of `console.log(...)` the *return value* was `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks. Problem solved by adding a semicolon. What a dark corner in the javascript.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen: One reason to always use semicolons.

Comment: But a very interesting question spawned from the “stylistic choice” to never use semicolons…

Comment: so is it because `console.log()()` its `console.log(...)` 3 dots not a function error, otherwise it should been just `console.log` is not function (only if it wasnt but actually it is)

Comment: @vinayakj Exactly. If something’s not a function then that function is always referd to by its function name, e. g. `object.method`, if you’re using the return value, especially in a chained method, it’ll be `object.method(...)`. It kinda takes the experience to know why you should always use semicolons, _and_ how to interpret JavaScript error messages correctly.

Comment: @Xufox `typeof console.log` returns `"function"` while `typeof console.anyFunctionYouCanImagineAtThisPointWillAlsoReturn` returns `"undefined"` as expected

Comment: @jcoig The code in the answer should actually throw an error. When I test it again, it actually does. I think an earlier Firefox version actually behaved differently.

Comment: legend. Was banging my head for ages for this, yet it's obvious when you understand what's going on, cheers

Comment: Because of issues like this it is sometimes recommended to always prefix IIFEs with a semicolon. That way if you move it around it wont risk breaking a missing semicolon elsewhere. Additionally if things get weird during minification/bundling it would be safer.

Comment: it is a bit amazing it is reporting `console.log(...) is not a function`. In some language it'd report `undefined is not a function`

Comment: Prefixing iifes with a semicolon is sound advice (better then "postfixing" everything else with one, imo). An even better one is not using iifes when you don't need them.

Answer (score 12):

The error means that the **return value** of `console.log()` is not a function. You are missing a semicolon:

```
console.log('xxx', $scope.tableIndexes[i].columnName[j]);
//                                                      ^
```

which makes the following `(...)` of the IIFE to be interpreted as a function call.

---

Compare the error messages of

```
> var foo = {bar: undefined};
> foo.bar();
Uncaught TypeError: foo.bar is not a function
```

and

```
> var foo = {bar: function(){}};
> foo.bar()();
Uncaught TypeError: foo.bar(...) is not a function
```

Answer (score 6):

#### 2020 Update

One possible cause can be the declaration of `var console` somewhere in your script.

Use:

```
window.console.log(...);
```

instead. Worked for me.

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I have the same problem and global.console.log works, why is this happening? How do I fix it and use the consol.log

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to encounter this error. `console.log` is not immutable and it is possible to accidentally overwrite the value.

```
console.log = 'hi';
```

In this case just reload the page to undo the damage.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not "THE" answer, but thought I would toss in the following

```
 var console = $( data.message_target );
 console.val( console.val() + data.message); 
 console.scrollTop(console[0].scrollHeight - console.height());
```

I had a textarea on the page I was calling "*console*". suddenly all my console.log() scripts gave the error **"Uncaught TypeError: console.log is not a function at Object"**

... and rightly so, because I used a reserved namespace for my object/var. I realized what I had done after reading his post, and for the sake of posterity: double check naming conventions.

cheers

*"its always human error"*

Answer (score -1):

In react-native at least, the console seems to work without any import, so, removing `import console = require('console');` or `import console from 'console';` from the begin of my file fixed it for me. (the VS Code IDE seems to add that automatically sometimes )