# Firefox/Firebug: Console.log("..."); causes TypeError: Console.log is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firebug, console.log

I can't find a solution to this. I've looked at [this previous question among others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013221/typeerror-console-log-is-not-a-function).

My code is simple:

```
$(function(){
    Console.log("Starting");
});
```

I have firebug open, with the Console tab selected, and the "JS" and "Logging" options selected. I get these two errors:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: Console.log is not a function
>
> TypeError: Console.log is not a function

What could be going wrong?

Comment: because it's `console.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using C instead of c:

```
$(function(){
    console.log("Starting");
});
```

Javascript functions and vars are case sensitive.