# Error when for having 2 immediately invoked functions in same page

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error for having to immediately invoked closures on the same page.... But if I only have one Immediately invoked the functions executes fine.. Wondering why this is the case.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(...) is not a function
>       at (index):57

```
<script>
(function(){
    var checkCharacater = function(word){
        for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            var count = 0;
            for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {
                if(word[i] == word[k]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == 1){
                return word[i];
            }  
        };
    }
    console.log(checkCharacater(teeter));
})()


//Design a progress bar that completes 100% in 5 seconds

(function(){
    var doc = document;
    var progressBar = doc.getElementById('progressBar');

    var doProgress = function(){
        progressBar.value++

        var intervalId = setTimeout(function(){
            doProgress()
        }, 50);
    }

    doProgress();
})()
```

Comment: That's literally the error message? Also, where is `teeter` defined?

Comment: I didn't write all of the code.... teeter is defined above....

Comment: I suggest giving your functions names and the invoking them via the names.

Comment: Put a semicolon between them (e.g. above the `//Design a progress bar …` comment). JavaScript parses the code like this: `(function(){})()(function(){})()`. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31013221/4642212.

Comment: Interesting.... I thought best practice is to not use semicolons in JS... Why did that work?

Comment: @SeenaKhoee Where have you read that?! Read the linked question and answer. It’s explained there.