# Functional expression using IIFE as a param?

Tags: javascript, iife, hoisting

The below works as intended

```
var dogName = function animalName(name) {
  console.log("My name is " + name);
}

dogName('Scruffy');

(function () {
    console.log("My name is Fido!");
})();
```

If you comment out dogName('Scruffy'); it outputs this

```
My name is function () {
  console.log("My name is Fido!");
}
```

If you adjust the IIFE to

```
(function () {
  console.log("My name is Fido!");
}()); // ()) instead of )()
```

It outputs

```
My name is Fido!
My name is undefined
```

Why does the functional expression use the IIFE as it's name variable, and why is the IIFE executed first before the functional expression in the last example?

Comment: If you comment out the intermediate line which contains a clear semicolon, it becomes `function animalName(name) {...}(function ...)`… An IIFE. Put a `;` after the definition of `animalName`.

Comment: Related: [`TypeError`: `console.log(`…`)` is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31013221/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't putting a semi-colon at the end of your function expression. Your code is essentially interpreted as this:

```
var dogName = function animalName(name) {
  console.log("My name is " + name);
}(function () {
    console.log("My name is Fido!");
})();
```

As far as the interpreter can tell, you're passing a function as the first argument to a named function expression then attempting to call the return value as a function.

To fix this, just put a semicolon at the end of the expression.

```js
var dogName = function animalName(name) {
  console.log("My name is " + name);
}; // <--

(function () {
    console.log("My name is Fido!");
})();
```