# Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Everything works fine when I wrote the js logic in a closure as a single js file, as:

```
(function(win){
   //main logic here
   win.expose1 = ....
   win.expose2 = ....
})(window)
```

but when I try to insert a logging alternative function before that closure in the same js file,

```
 window.Glog = function(msg){
     console.log(msg)
 }
 // this was added before the main closure.

 (function(win){
   //the former closure that contains the main javascript logic;
 })(window)
```

it complains that there is a TypeError:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013221/typeerror-console-log-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 445, accepted):

The error is a result of the missing semicolon on the third line:

```
window.Glog = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}; // <--- Add this semicolon

(function(win) {
  // ...
})(window);
```

The ECMAScript specification has [specific rules for automatic semicolon insertion](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9), however in this case a semicolon isn't automatically inserted because the parenthesised expression that begins on the next line can be interpreted as an argument list for a function call.

This means that without that semicolon, the anonymous `window.Glog` function was being invoked with a function as the `msg` parameter, followed by `(window)` which was subsequently attempting to invoke whatever was returned.

This is how the code was being interpreted:

```
window.Glog = function(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
}(function(win) {
  // ...
})(window);
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation Josh, and @mrlew, your answer is helpful too, no need to delete that :-)

Comment: @armnotstrong Josh was faster, and the answer is the same :)

Comment: Thank you sir! My linter removed the semicolon automagically and everything broke :)

Comment: awesome!!! Thank you so much!! I almost lost all my hair on this one...

Comment: Err.... totally forgot about that. It was 2nd nature back in the jQuery days!

Comment: this is insane and I'm so grateful for this post. I was setting state after an `if` statement in a React `useEffect()` function when I kept receiving this "... is not a function" error.

Comment: This type of error you can have, if you have condition for rendering and have missed logical operator like "&&" or "||".

{condition && condition && condition __here is missing &&-||__ <App />}

Answer (score 29):

## To make semicolon rules simple

Every line that begins with a `(`, `[`, `, or any arithmetic operator, *must* begin with a semicolon if you want it to be interpreted as its own line ~ Otherwise, it may combine with the previous line by accident. All other line breaks have implicit semicolons.

That's it. Done.

- Note that /, +, - are the only valid operators you would want to do this for anyway. You would never want a line to begin with '*', since it's a binary operator that could never make sense at the beginning of a line.
- You should put the semicolons at the *start* of the line when doing this. You should not try to "fix" the issue by adding a semicolon to the *previous* line, or any reordering or moving of the code will cause the issue to potentially manifest again. Many of the other answers (including top answers) make this suggestion, but it's not a good practice.

---

### Why do those particular characters need initial semicolons?

Consider the following:

```
func()
;[0].concat(myarr).forEach(func)
;(myarr).forEach(func)
;`hello`.forEach(func)
;/hello/.exec(str)
;+0
;-0
```

By following the rules given, you prevent the above code from being reinterpreted as

```
func()[0].concat(myarr).forEach(func)(myarr).forEach(func)`hello`.forEach(func)/hello/.forEach(func)+0-0
```

### Additional Notes

To mention what will happen: brackets will index, parentheses will be treated as function parameters. The backtick would transform into a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), regex will turn into division, and explicitly +/- signed integers will turn into plus/minus operators.

Of course, you can avoid this by just adding a semicolon to the end of every linebreak, but do *not* believe that doing this can let you code like a C programmer. Since it is still the case that when you *don't* end a line with a semicolon, Javascript might implicitly add one on your behalf against your desires. So, keep in mind statements like

```
return       // Implicit semicolon, will return undefined.
    (1+2);

i        // Implicit semicolon on this line
   ++;   // But, if you really intended "i++;"
         // and you actually wrote it like this,
         // you need help.
```

The above case will happen to return/continue/break/++/--. Any linter will catch the former case with dead-code, or the latter case with ++/-- syntax error.

Finally, if you want file concatenation to work, make sure each file ends with a semicolon. If you're using a bundler program (recommended), it should do this automatically.

Answer (score 11):

**Error Case:**

```
var userListQuery = {
    userId: {
        $in: result
    },
    "isCameraAdded": true
}

( cameraInfo.findtext != "" ) ? searchQuery : userListQuery;
```

**Output:**

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function
```

**Fix:** You are missing a semi-colon (;) to separate the expressions

```
userListQuery = {
    userId: {
        $in: result
    },
    "isCameraAdded": true
}; // Without a semi colon, the error is produced

( cameraInfo.findtext != "" ) ? searchQuery : userListQuery;
```

Answer (score 7):

For me it was much more simple but it took me a while to figure it out. We basically had in our .jslib

```js
some_array.forEach(item => {
    do_stuff(item);
});
```

Turns out Unity (emscripten?) just doesn't like that syntax. We replaced it with a good old for-loop and it stoped complaining right away.
I really hate it that it doesn't show the line it is complaining about, but anyway, fool me twice shame on me.

Comment: my guess is that your issue was something to do with [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: This is a different case than what the question is about.

Comment: @CherryDT it is not, since the error I was getting was the exact same one.

Comment: No, this question is about errors you get from accidentally calling something as a function due to no semicolon existing between the statement and a `(` on the next line. I don't see any of that in your case. The question doesn't only consist of its title!

Answer (score 7):

When I create a root class, whose methods I defined using the arrow functions. When inheriting and overwriting the original function I noticed the same issue.

```
class C {
  x = () => 1; 
 };
 
class CC extends C {
  x = (foo) =>  super.x() + foo;
};

let add = new CC;
console.log(add.x(4));
```

this is solved by defining the method of the parent class without arrow functions

```
class C {
  x() { 
    return 1; 
  }; 
 };
 
class CC extends C {
  x = foo =>  super.x() + foo;
};

let add = new CC;
console.log(add.x(4));
```

Comment: `Function.bind` requires this strategy also--thanks

Comment: I believe this is because an arrow function is a property in the object, while a method is a property in the prototype. So when `super.x()` tries to reference the prototype's property `x`, it's not there (`x = () => 1;` is in the object itself). This is mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#arrow-functions):  _"You can’t use super.getName in a derived class, because there’s no entry in the prototype chain to fetch the base class method from"_.

Comment: Thank you! I was having this exact problem and couldn't figure it out. And thank you @Branko Dimitrijevic for the explanation.

Comment: Unfortunatelly in my case, I'd like to have two possible candidates for my method, which seems impossible. Worked fine until I extended parent class... I mean, I can have some 1 uniform class method, that calls another method, it just looks ugly and I need to hope, that it will get optimized properly.

Answer (score 6):

```
  **Error Case:**

var handler = function(parameters) {
  console.log(parameters);
}

(function() {     //IIFE
 // some code
})();
```

**Output: TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function
*How to Fix IT -> because you are missing semi colan(;) to separate expressions;**

```
 **Fixed**


var handler = function(parameters) {
  console.log(parameters);
}; // <--- Add this semicolon(if you miss that semi colan .. 
   //error will occurs )

(function() {     //IIFE
 // some code
})();
```

why this error comes??
  Reason :
 [specific rules for automatic semicolon insertion which is given ES6 stanards](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.9)

Answer (score 5):

I faced same issue with this situation:

```js
let brand, capacity, color;
let car = {
  brand: 'benz',
  capacity: 80,
  color: 'yellow',
}

({ color, capacity, brand } = car);
```

And with just a `;` at the end of `car` declaration the error disappred:

```js
let car = {
  brand: 'benz',
  capacity: 80,
  color: 'yellow',
}; // <-------------- here a semicolon is needed
```

Actually, before `({ color, capacity, brand } = car);` it is needed to see semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this issue when I created a new ES2015 class where the property name was equal to the method name.

e.g.:

```
class Test{
  constructor () {
    this.test = 'test'
  }

  test (test) {
    this.test = test
  }
}

let t = new Test()
t.test('new Test')
```

Please note this implementation was in NodeJS 6.10.

As a workaround (if you do not want to use the boring 'setTest' method name), you could use a prefix for your 'private' properties (like `_test`).

Open your Developer Tools in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5y5vrL5m).

Comment: This is a different case than what the question is about.

Answer (score 1):

If using Next.JS, this error might popup if you're trying to import a module from a file with `"use server";` at the top.

In my case, I exported a zod schema in a server action and tried to import that schema into a client-side component. Simply move the schema to a separate file (without `"use server";` at the top) to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My case: (Angular, PrimeNG )

My Error:
[image]
My versions:

```
 "@angular/animations": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/common": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/forms": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.0",
 "@angular/router": "^12.2.0",
 "primeng": "^13.0.0-rc.2",
 "quill": "^1.3.7"
```

My solution:
node_modules/primeng/fesm2015/primeng-editor.mjs

update the import for Quill like in the image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in **React** and it took me ages to figure out the problem,

[image]

The cause was not wrapping context around my app

[image]

Go to your index.jsx (or main.jsx in ViteJS) and check that you have Context wrapped around your app.

Answer (score 0):

If comming from Ionic Angular update to latest version

```
ng update @ionic/angular
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error trying to connect zod validation with formik in React + TypeScript yo need to install zod-formik-adapter.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35471373)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with this situation:
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is undefined

```
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import { setUser } from "../redux/userSlice";
import { showLoading, hideLoading } from "../redux/alertsSlice";

function ProtectedRoute(props) {
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      dispatch(showLoading());
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/api/user/get-user-info-by-id",
        { token: localStorage.getItem("token") },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
          },
        }
      );
      dispatch(hideLoading());
      if (response.data.success) {
        dispatch(setUser(response.data.data));
      } else {
        localStorage.clear();
        navigate("/login");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(hideLoading());
      localStorage.clear();
      navigate("/login");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [user]);

  if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
    return props.children;
  } else {
    return navigate("/login");
  }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could include some explanation or commentary. Specifically, it would be great if you could address the main points of replying a question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).