# Why am I getting Uncaught TypeError: sendToServer(...) is not a function in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am making a messaging system using firebase. It properly sends messages to firebase, however when I send messages, it keeps throwing the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: sendToServer(...) is not a function
    at sendToP.js:21
    at EventRegistration.ts:109
    at Qe (util.ts:539)
    at EventQueue.ts:159
    at Pi (EventQueue.ts:127)
    at Ii (EventQueue.ts:107)
    at wo (Repo.ts:365)
    at ro.s.server_ [as onDataUpdate_] (Repo.ts:230)
    at ro.onDataPush_ (PersistentConnection.ts:661)
    at ro.onDataMessage_ (PersistentConnection.ts:654)
```

Here is the function that adds the message to the database

```
function cleanMessage(message){
  message = message.split(" ").map(x => badWords.indexOf(x) != -1? x = (x.split("").map(c => c = '*')).join(""): x = x).join(" ")
  return message
}

function sendToServer(obj) {
  autoId = firebase.database().ref('users').push().key
  firebase.database().ref('/general/' + autoId.toString()).set(obj)
}

$(".send").click(function() {
  firebase.database().ref('Users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    digits = snapshot.val().digits
    let message = cleanMessage($(".enter-message").val())

    let messageObject = {
      message: message,
      sender: digits
    }
    sendToServer(messageObject)
    $(".enter-message").val('') 
  });
})
```

Here is the function that gets the last message. Note: This is on a separate script

```
// Add message to the browser window

firebase.database().ref('general').orderByKey().limitToLast(1).on("value", function(snapshot){
  message = ""
  snapshot.forEach(function(elem){
    message = elem.val().message
  })
})
```

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Why is `($(".enter-message").val('')) ` in `(` `)` remove it

Comment: It happened by accident when I copy-pasted from another script, I fixed it. thanks 

Comment: `console.log(sendToServer);` So what is it?

Comment: I don't see that in my script, could you please tell me which line it is on?

Comment: I mean log out what it is so you can see what the script is complaining about.

Comment: Oh ok my bad lol

Comment: I don't think sendToServer is producing any errors.. I think there's a function block below and confusion is taking place(reads 2 separate instructions as one)

Comment: Could you please tell me where I can learn more about this? Also, what are the extra brackets for at the end?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036349/uncaught-typeerror-intermediate-value-is-not-a-function#42036382 shows an example where not placing a semi colon or placing one literally means something very different(using newline doesn't help in certain instances)

Comment: It says sendToServer is not defined now, not sure what I did wrong

Comment: well word.. sendToServer didn't return anything.. is the error still happening?
if not, could u pls mark :D

Comment: I am getting a reference error now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230382/discussion-between-the-bomb-squad-and-jhon).

Comment: @epascarello you are correct.. completely

Comment: thank you all for your help