# TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function at async Promise.all

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am refactoring my index file that creates all my models in Sequelize to use imports instead of require with the switch to Node v14 and Sequelize v6 and modules.  But I am stuck on this weird error:

`TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function at file:///C:/.../models/index.js:41:6 at async Promise.all (index 0)`

Here is the code block where it is happening:

```js
fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, files) => {
    console.log('in the readdir!!');
    if (err) {
        console.log({ err });
    } else {
        console.log('the else!');
        console.log({ files });
        const promise_arr = files
            .filter((file) => {
                return (
                    file.indexOf('.') !== 0 &&
                    file !== basename &&
                    file.slice(-3) === '.js'
                );
            })
            .map(async (file) => {
                // const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
                console.log({ file });
                console.log({ __dirname });
                return (
                    await import('file:///' + path.join(__dirname, file))
                )(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
            });
        console.log({ promise_arr });
        Promise.all(promise_arr)
            .then((models) => {
                models.forEach((model) => (db[model.name] = model));
                associateCB();
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log({ e }));
    }
});

function associateCB() {
    console.log('associateCB with: ', db);
    Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
        if (db[modelName].associate) {
            db[modelName].associate(db);
        }
    });
    console.log(1, { db });
}
```

And the error says it is happening on this line: `)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);`

Comment: The line you indicate is a function invocation. The error message says something is not a function. It seems clear to me that the value produced by `await import('file:///' + path.join(__dirname, file))` is not a function; find out what it is.

Comment: OK, so I did this: `const fileImport = await import('file:///' + path.join(__dirname, file));
 console.log(typeof fileImport);`.  And I got a type of object.

Comment: That's it then! You can't perform the function call `fileImport(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)` if `fileImport` is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might be a semicolon issue? See: [Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036349/uncaught-typeerror-intermediate-value-is-not-a-function)

```
return (
    await import('file:///' + path.join(__dirname, file)); // <--- Add this semicolon
)(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
```

Comment: That causes a syntax error in the code.  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'`

Comment: Ah. Sorry. :/ Hopefully you've figured things out by now.