# discord.js .setToken(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am new in `discord.js v14.0.3` and trying to start a simple command but I got an error.
I checked my `BOT_TOKEN`, `BOT_CLIENT_ID`, `GUILD_ID` is valid and I think the problem is not related with those token, how can I fix it?

**Error Message**

```
> node register.js

/register.js:11
(async () => {
^

TypeError: (intermediate value).setToken(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> ....
```

**My code**

```
require("dotenv").config()

const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest')
const { Routes } = require('discord.js')

const commands = [
  {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'Replies with Pong!',
  },
];

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)

(async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.')

    await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(process.env.BOT_CLIENT_ID, process.env.DC_GUILD_ID), { body: commands });

    console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.')
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
})()
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "node register.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42036349/uncaught-typeerror-intermediate-value-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. Looks like your `package.json` is missing `@discordjs/rest`. Install it with `npm install @discordjs/rest` or whatever your package manager is. Since you have no error on the `require` it may be is installed as phantom dependency.
2. You simply missing a semicolon in the line `const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)` therfore the whole block with `...setToken...(async ()` is considered to be one(!) expression.

Comment: for point1, try to install the module and still getting error

Comment: and for point2, yup it works after I insert `;` :) thanks!

Comment: You were using a package in your app which was not present in `package.json`. Due to the nature of package resolution and flattening of `node_modules` this can work because of dependencies of your dependencies. Like A uses B and B uses C. When A uses C it just works as long as B has C as dependency. Imagine an update for B where C is dropped => A get's errors by just updating packages which seems to be totally unrelated. This is a phantom dependency or phantom child and bad practice. Since you had no error on the require, I was sure that it will not solve your problem but should be done.