# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function even though it works on JsFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

The JSFiddle in question seems to have no trouble: http://jsfiddle.net/S3LF3/ (if you type a url like google.com it will select the value of ".com" or whatever you put after the dot and it is in the list)

However the jQuery function seems to be faulty?

In chrome I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ready(...) is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Site</title>

    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/msdropdown/dd.css" />
    <script src="js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/msdropdown/flags.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add new site</h1>
<div class="contentbox">
<form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="addsite" value="true"/>
            <p>
            <label for="site_url">Site url:</label>
            <input type="text" name="site_url" id="urlText" placeholder="domain.xxx" value=""/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="site_url">Search locale:</label>
        <select name="locale" id="locale">
            <option value="">
              Select locale
            </option>
             <optgroup label="Popular">
<option value=".dk" data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag dk" data-title="Denmark">Denmark - Danish</option>
                                                                                <option value=".de" data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag de" data-title="Germany">Germany - German</option>
  <option value=".au" data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag au" data-title="Australia">Australia - English</option>

  </optgroup>
            </select>
          </p>

        <p>
            <label for="site_url"></label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn" value="Add">
        </p>


</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#locale").msDropdown();
})


(function ($) {
    $('#urlText').on('change', function () {
        var value = this.value,
            parts = this.value.split('.'),
            str, $opt;
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            str = '.' + parts.slice(i).join('.');
            $opt = $('#locale option[value="' + str + '"]');
            if ($opt.length) {
                $opt.prop('selected', true);
                break;
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

What I want to do is when a user types a url, like "google.dk" , it should select the value with ".dk" at the end from the dropdown for him.

Comment: have you included your jquery file and is it in the correct place and loaded?

Comment: yes, it loads jquery just fine

Comment: It did not change anything

Comment: What happens if you remove the document ready function and add the 
`$("#locale").msDropdown();` above the  `$('#urlText')` in the other function?

Comment: I managed to get rid of the error with Flanagan's suggestion. But the script is not doing anything it seems.

Comment: Could it be something to do with this: https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-document-ready-handlers-other-than-jquery-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013221/typeerror-console-log-is-not-a-function) — Read the error carefully. `$(…).ready(…)` is not a function, which means in your code there’s something like `$(…).ready(…)()`. So put a semicolon at the right place to avoid this.

Answer (score 2):

I played with your code and found out, it's the missing semicolon at the end of $(document).ready();

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#locale").msDropdown();
    });
```

Just try it in the built-in editor:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add Site</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/msdropdown/dd.css" />
    <script src="js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/msdropdown/flags.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add new site</h1>
<div class="contentbox">
<form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="addsite" value="true"/>
            <p>
            <label for="site_url">Site url:</label>
            <input type="text" name="site_url" id="urlText" placeholder="domain.xxx" value=""/>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="site_url">Search locale:</label>
        <select name="locale" id="locale">
            <option value="">
              Select locale
            </option>
             <optgroup label="Popular">
<option value=".dk" data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag dk" data-title="Denmark">Denmark - Danish</option>
                                                                                <option value=".de" data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag de" data-title="Germany">Germany - German</option>
  <option value=".au" data-image="images/msdropdown/icons/blank.gif" data-imagecss="flag au" data-title="Australia">Australia - English</option>

  </optgroup>
            </select>
          </p>

        <p>
            <label for="site_url"></label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn" value="Add">
        </p>


</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//$("#locale").msDropdown();
});


(function ($) {
    $('#urlText').on('change', function () {
        var value = this.value,
            parts = this.value.split('.'),
            str, $opt;
        for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            str = '.' + parts.slice(i).join('.');
            $opt = $('#locale option[value="' + str + '"]');
            if ($opt.length) {
                $opt.prop('selected', true);
                break;
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: it seems that it does work without the jquery.dd.min.js that I am using from here http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags . Can I someone have it working while keeping this JS script?

Comment: I even tried using the old jQuery that this guy is using but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery shortcut - $() - seems to have been overridden by another library is my guess.

Try using:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
```

Comment: No longer getting the error, but the script doesn't do what I want it to, still

Comment: is it possible that because its older jQuery, some syntax must be changed to work with 3.1.1 ?

Comment: Saved my life after hours of searching. This was it., even though in my case it was $.post, changed to jQuery.post after seeing this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the JSFiddle works fine is it doesn't actually use the country flag drop down menu plugin you found. The way the plugin works is different than the way a standard `<select>` html tag works.

I looked inside the jquery.dd.js file, and it seems there is no way to interact with the dropdown menu using javascript. Therefore, your line `$opt.prop('selected', true);` is valid for a real drop down menu (a `<select>` tag), but not for the plugin's drop down menu, which handles the selected state differently. Also, the plugin provides little documentation and has little to no comments in the code, so this makes it diffcult to know how the plugin works.

I can see 2 solutions to your problem:

1. You can try to understand the plugin's code in the `jquery.dd.js` file and try to implement a way to tell the plugin which element you want to select. I wouldn't normally recommend editing third-party plugins, but since the site you got the plugin from has not been updated since 2012, there is little chance for the plugin to receive updates in the future, so editing it would be safe in this case. It will require some knowledge in jQuery plugin making, though.
2. You can try to find another country flag drop down plugin that can be updated using javascript instead of using your mouse only. Such projects can be found on Github (here are some results found on Github: [Country flag drop down menu results on Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=country%20flags%20dropdown)).

**Previous information found:**

From the code you provided, you are missing a semi-colon after the call of the `$(document).ready()` function. It should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#locale").msDropdown();
}); // <--- This semi-colon is missing
```

Also, the code in `(function ($) {// code} )(jQuery);` may be executed **before** the document was ready, which means this code could sometimes not work. Try putting this code inside your `$(document).ready();` anonymous function. This way, you will be sure all html nodes will be accessible by jQuery.

Finally, you should consider putting your javascript logic somewhere inside the `<html>` tag (inside the `<head>`, right after `<body>` or right before `</body>`). While putting the `<script>` tag after the `</html>` tag may work at first, this is far from valid html and may be the cause of some problems you're having. The best way would be to put your javascript in a `.js` file and link it in your `<head>` the same way you linked jQuery and msdropdown:

```
<head>
    <!-- Your other linked files... -->
    <script src="js/main-logic.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Did this, but it seems that it works if I take out the jquery.dd.min.js , http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/countries-dropdown-flags this guy's js that I needed for the country flags to appear on the dropdown. Is there any way to override this behavior and have both working?

Comment: @crystyxn I updated my answer with new information. I think the plugin doesn't actually has any way of changing its state using javascript. See my answer for more details.