# why is console.log is giving an error that is not a function type?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am suddenly getting the below error . I havent changed anything in this controller recently to get this error.

Has anyone seen a similar issue before or know how to fix this? My browsers havent changed or updated, and it was working fine until yesterday.

**Chrome**
TypeError: console.log is not a function

**IE**
TypeError: Function expected

```
 CreateBankCtrl.$inject = ['CommonService'];

  function CreateBankCtrl(CommonService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.apiAlerts = [];
        console.log("Creating the controller");
}
```

Comment: Did something override console? What browser are you in?

Comment: Old IE didn't define `console` unless you had devtools open.

Comment: Just updated with few more details

Comment: So set a break point and look what console is.

Comment: You could try using `window.console.log`, in case `console` is shadowed by a local variable.

Comment: Maybe is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013221/typeerror-console-log-is-not-a-function/31013390. Do you have IIFEs near to that console.log invocation?

Comment: Can't really be reproduced, `console.log` is defined in Chrome, and doesn't cause issue like that, unless there is other code interferring that we can't see ?

Comment: Check if you have created any variable named `console`. Type `console` in the developer console and hit enter, see what you get.

Comment: @VictorArcas -  All my controllers are enclosed in an IIFE

Comment: @alice are you sure the browser error is pointing to this console.log and not other?

Comment: @VictorArcas - I setup a breakpoint and console does point to a valid object . It does hit the same error output line on break point

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the issue,

I had inadvertently introduced an equals to operation ("=")

```
console.log = ("fetched user permissions " + $localStorage.userPermissions);
```

this had overridden the log function. I have lint setup with strict mode on. But the above was not caught. Can lint be configured to capture such issues?

Answer (score 0):

It could be your browser, or some cache, try to clear it and open fresh browser. It works for me. I hope this will help you out.