# How to destructure this Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructure

How do I destructure `width` and `height` if they have been declared before?

```
function test() {
  let height
  let width

  const viewBox = '0 0 24 24'
  const sizeArr = viewBox.split(' ')

  // ESLint is telling me to destructure these and I don't know how
  width = sizeArr[2]
  height = sizeArr[3]
}
```

Comment: [   ,     ,  width  ,  height] = sizeArr.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a comma to ignore certain elements of the array that you do not need:

```
const [,,width,height] = sizeArr;
```

```js
function test() {
  const viewBox = '0 0 24 24'
  const sizeArr = viewBox.split(' ')
  const [,,width,height]=sizeArr;
  console.log(width,height);
}
test();
```

If you need to keep the `let` declarations at the top of the function for some reason, you can remove the `const` from destructuring. Note that you will need a semicolon at the end of the preceding line due to automatic semicolon insertion.

```
[,,width,height] = sizeArr;
```

```js
function test() {
  let height;
  let width;
  const viewBox = '0 0 24 24';
  const sizeArr = viewBox.split(' ');
  [,,width,height]=sizeArr;
  console.log(width,height);
}
test();
```

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Ignoring_some_returned_values

If you do need every value, declare a name for each one:

```
const [var1,var2,width,height] = sizeArr;
```

```js
function test() {
  const viewBox = '0 0 24 24'
  const sizeArr = viewBox.split(' ')
  const [var1,var2,width,height]=sizeArr;
  console.log(var1,var2,width,height);
}
test();
```

Comment: I never considered this option because I expected ESLint to complain about empty array slots.

Comment: Nice, didn't know you could leave blanks

Comment: So even though I'm writing `const`, it won't have a conflict with `width` and `height` being declared above as `let`?

Comment: @RossMoody You would have a conflict. Remove the `let` declarations. You don’t need them.

Comment: @RossMoody Remove the `let` statements. See the code snippet in my answer.

Comment: @RossMoody If you don’t want to remove the `let` declarations (not sure why you wouldn’t), then use `[,, width, height] = sizeArr;`, but please put a semicolon after `viewBox.split(" ")`, or else you’ll get one of [these ASI errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31013221/4642212).

Comment: @RossMoody I've updated my answer in case you need the `let` declarations.

Comment: @user4642212 You are actually the person who got the answer I needed. This is a slimmed down version of the larger function where I declare those variables in an upper scope. The semicolon is why I was getting the error. THANK YOU

Comment: @RossMoody You should have provided more context at the start in that case.

Answer (score 3):

`const [first, second, width, height] = sizeArr;`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply destructure the array into the already-declared variables:

```
let height;
let width;

const viewBox = '0 0 24 24';
const sizeArr = viewBox.split(' ');

[width, height] = sizeArr.slice(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let [,,width,height] = arr;
console.log('%s %s', width, height);
```