# TestCafe: console.log() the value of a selector

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I try to select the text value *SR-12948* of the span below with a TestCafe selector and then assign it to a const. So I can add it as a string to the withAttribute method. That doesn't really work. So I want to check what the value of my const srCaseIDString is. Is it possible to do that with a console log? So it logs the value of that const in the same terminal as my test results and errors appear?

This is my test:

```
<span data-template="" data-test-id="2014100715101007275150" class="supporting_text_il" style="">SR-12948</span>

import { Selector, t } from "testcafe";
import XPathSelector from "../utils/xpath-selector";

const button= Selector("#button");  

test("First Test", async (t) => {
     await t
        .click(button);

        const srCaseID = await  XPathSelector("//span[@data-test-id='2014100715101007275150']").innerText;

        console.log(srCaseID);

        const iframeCase = await Selector('iframe').withAttribute('title', srCaseIDString);
       
        await t
        .switchToIframe(iframeCase);
     
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innertext` != `innerText`, it is case sensitive.

This works just fine:

```js
const elementInnerText = await Selector('#id').innerText;
console.log(elementInnerText);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the case sensitive issue. But I receive the error: TypeError: console.log is not a function. When running the test. So I'm still not able of console logging the value of the selector.

Comment: Does something here solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013221/typeerror-console-log-is-not-a-function ? Like putting a semicolon there after the statement, or making sure you don't define console variable anywhere else.

Comment: Oh damn, I did define a console variable somewhere else. In a different file that I import in this test. Thank you very much for pointing that out! :)