# I'm having trouble getting a button with onclick method that calls a js function to work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, onclick

The basic premise of this app is like a radio that saves stations to certain channels to be recalled when clicked. I keep getting the ***index.html:111 Uncaught ReferenceError: saveOne is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:111)***
error in the console and also when I mouse over the function in my VSCode i get this error: ***'saveOne' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)***

I've looked everywhere for a while now and can't find any solution or clear explanation as to why it's not working.

Thanks!

//HTML//
sorry I'm new to stack overflow ::facepalm:: I assure you the html is accurate, but I don't understand how to get it to work since im a stack overflow noob.

```
button onclick="" value="90.1" type="button" id="channel1" class="btn btn-secondary">One /button>

button type="button" onclick="saveOne()" id="save1" class="btn btn-dark save_btns">Save1 /button>
```

// JS FILE //

```
let channel1 = document.getElementById("channel1").value

function saveOne(){
    let saveChnl1 = current_station.innerHTML
    channel1 = saveChnl1
    // console.log(channel1) //100.3
    return channel1
    
}
```

Comment: Did you forget the semicolon at the end?

Comment: How the HTML and JavaScript files come together? Of you are using TypeScript, then you must have a build step of some sort, right?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE ... know that javascript generally does not explicitly need `;`, as javacript handles _automatic semicolon insertion_, or [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion)

Comment: @PaulT. [without the semicolon a lot of weird stuff can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013390/15578194)

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE ... I believe it. Thanks for the link info. I use semicolons myself with javascript (habit of C/C++, Java, and PHP coding), as I don't like to rely on the automatic handling, but I'm sure weird things can surely happen. I've seen quite a bit of javascript code without terminating `;` usage over the years. (even within some js frameworks)

Comment: It's not the semicolon... even with those in place it still has the same errors. ty tho!

Answer (score 0):

OK there are so many things wrong with your question so I'll help you out.

Firstly, your html is completely invalid as it is missing correct open and close brackets.

```html
button onclick="" value="90.1" type="button" id="channel1" class="btn btn-secondary">One /button>

button type="button" onclick="saveOne()" id="save1" class="btn btn-dark save_btns">Save1 /button>
```

Should be

```html
<button value="90.1" type="button" id="channel1" class="btn btn-secondary">One</button>

<button type="button" onclick="saveOne()" id="save1" class="btn btn-dark save_btns">Save1</button>
```

Secondly, if you import your script *correctly*, you wont get any not defined errors.

Make sure that in your html `head` tag, you have a `script` tag with a `src` attribute like so:

```html
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

and make sure that the path is correct. For information about html pathing, see [HTML File Paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Lastly, the javascript you provided wasn't valid either, but I'll assume that it uses some kind of global reference.

Comment: The JS file is loaded and does work, I always test it out with an alert to be sure, and I have other functions running that work just fine. Ty tho!