# “`TypeError`: `[0,1]` is not a function” is thrown when using an IIFE

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, iife

Here is the code

```js
var numberArray = [0, 1]

(function() {
  numberArray.push(2)

  function nestedFunction() {
    numberArray.push(3)

    function anotherNestedFunction() {
      numberArray.push(4)
    }

    console.log(numberArray)
  }
})()
```

I am expecting `numberArray` with value `[0,1,2,3,4]` but it is giving this error:

> `TypeError`: `[0,1]` is not a function

Comment: Put a semicolon at the end of the `var` line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immediately invoked function expression throws "object is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031820/immediately-invoked-function-expression-throws-object-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var numberArray = [0, 1]
(function() {
```

is equivalent to

```
var numberArray = [0, 1] (function() {
```

That is where the error rise.

To resolve the issue place `;` after the array declaration which JavaScript engine will consider both the line as separate statement:

```js
var numberArray = [0, 1];

(function() {
  numberArray.push(2);

  function nestedFunction() {
    numberArray.push(3);

    function anotherNestedFunction() {
      numberArray.push(4);
    }
    
    anotherNestedFunction();
    console.log(numberArray);
  }
  nestedFunction();
})();
```

To ignore all these unexpected issue, it is always good practice to use semicolons (`;`) after every statement in JavaScript.

Comment: Good to know why I'm using semicolons at the end of every line in JS :D (I just knew it could cause issues, but I've never seen an actual case of it)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working snippet

```js
const numberArray = [0, 1];

(function() {
  numberArray.push(2);

  (function nestedFunction() {
    numberArray.push(3);

    (function anotherNestedFunction() {
      numberArray.push(4);
    })();

    console.log(numberArray);
  })();
})();
```

---

If you remove the `;` after `numberArray` this is where you got a problem. You also have to use IIFE with your inner declared `functions`.

```js
const numberArray = [0, 1]

(function() {
  numberArray.push(2);

  (function nestedFunction() {
    numberArray.push(3);

    (function anotherNestedFunction() {
      numberArray.push(4);
    })();

    console.log(numberArray);
  })();
})();
```