# IIFE. TypeError: require(...)(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, iife

Running simple **script**. Got an error.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const url = "https://www.someurl.com"

(async ()=>{
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response
    console.log(data)
})()
```

**ERROR**

> $ node api.js TypeError: require(...)(...) is not a function

What am I missing here ?
Thank you.

Comment: an `;`  before your IIFE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Immediately invoked function expression throws "object is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031820/immediately-invoked-function-expression-throws-object-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Automatic Semicolon Insertion(ASI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Semicolon_insertion) doesn't work as you expect it to in some cases.

[IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)s fall into one of those cases, where the parentheses are concatenated with previous line code.

To ameliorate this, just prefix your IIFE's with a semicolon:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const url = "https://www.someurl.com"

;(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url)
    console.log(response)
})()
```

Or as @estus suggests in the comments, just avoid writing semicolon-less code.

Comment: I'd suggest to do the opposite thing and just don't rely on ASI. This code style is weird (hey, [Standard](https://github.com/standard/standard)) and causes more problems than it solves, just a bad habit that a dev will need to get rid eventually.

Comment: @estus I wholeheartedly disagree but I guess it all comes down to preference.