# Async/Await is only valid async func while reading a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I was trying to read a `JSON` file using Async/Await, I created my example based [Native async/await approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593875/using-filesystem-in-node-js-with-async-await), and I got this error.

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Here is my code.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');  
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

const path = "file.json";

function parseJM() {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(path, { encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, data) => {
        if (err) { reject(err); }
        else {
            resolve (parser.parseString(data.replace(/<ent_seq>[0-9]*<\/ent_seq>/g, "")
             .replace(/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/g, '')));
        }
    });
});
}

const var1 = await parseJM();
console.log(var1);
```

What is wrong with my code? My node version is 11.9.0, my npm version is 6.7.0 and i am using Arch Linux.

Comment: What is wrong with my code? ---> await is only valid in async function, like you've already answered in your question

Comment: The error told you exactly what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Your using `fs-extra` here, so don't even bother using `new Promise`..  `All fs methods return promises if the callback isn't passed.`

Comment: The purpose of writing like this, the promise is not enough for by itself.

Comment: I do not understand why the heck this community so harsh on people

Comment: @KaanTahaKöken As it was noticed, `new Promise` is an antipattern. It's never needed when you have existing promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call await inside an async function.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const var1 = await parseJM();
        console.log(var1);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }
})();
```

Edit: As suggested by @Nik Kyriakides

Comment: `try/catch` is a must when you do this. Otherwise you're setting yourself up for swallowed errors.

Comment: is it possible without using IFFE's

Comment: @KaanTahaKöken Yes, you can use a `.then`/`resolve` since `async`-marked functions return a `Promise`.

Comment: @NikKyriakides Not exactly swallowed. You will get `"unhandledRejection"` if an error is thrown inside `parseJM()` call.

Comment: @Aikei True, bad choice of words.

Answer (score 2):

The error itself is telling you exactly what the issue is. You can only `await` inside an `async`-marked function.

If that's your top-level code you can just use an `async` [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
;(async () => {
  try {
    await doSomething()  
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
```

or just `then`/`catch` it. `async` functions return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) after all:

```
doSomething() 
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
  })
```

Comment: Why the `;`? Is it a typo or a clever hack I didn't know about?

Comment: Just to make sure that you don't fall into [this trap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53186265/iife-typeerror-require-is-not-a-function/53186477#53186477).

Comment: That's how code looks when you don't use semi-colons consistently. Not really my thing.

Comment: Apart from IIFE's I've *never* had to prefix anything with a `;`. My take is that it's far better w/o them.