# Javascript strange loading sequence

Tags: javascript

In the code below I expected to see the following sequence

```
1, 2, loaded
```

but I get

```
1, loaded, 2
```

Why?

```
<html>
<script>
window.onload = function()
{
    alert('loaded');
}

(function ()
{
    alert('1');
}());

(function ()
{
    alert('2');
}());

</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This also happens with `console.log`, instead of the blocking `alert`: http://jsfiddle.net/9fSgE/.

Comment: @HalimQarroum what's the difference? It's just the way you write it, and makes more sense to execute the function `()` inside it's context `());` and as in any language we have agreed to use  the correct punctuation makes sense to do the same in JS. Same for the *lost curl*, it would be better to use it in the same line where the function is stated.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, I thought also that was something to do with the *blocking* of `alert()`, seems not to be the case. Neither makes difference placing the calls in `head` or before `</body>`

Comment: Playing around a bit: If you add direct `console.log` calls between the IIFE's, you can see that `loaded` is directly called after the first IIFE terminates: http://jsfiddle.net/9fSgE/1. However, if you unwrap the first IIFE, then the `loaded` call appears at the very end, not after the second IIFE: http://jsfiddle.net/9fSgE/2/. Unfortunately this doesn't bring me any closer to an explanation :-/

Comment: +1 Fascinating question. Can't wait for a decent explanation. Would be better updated to the `console.log` version as this, to me, is truly mystifying, whereas with `alert` it seems to make more sense.

Comment: Same problem, slightly different question: [Why is this grouping operator + function immediatly invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14810951/218196)

Comment: This particular problem is very hard to search for, but it's been asked dozens of times on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You forgot `;` after window `onload` function expression. So it becomes:

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('loaded');
}(function() { console.log('1'); }())
```

So `onload` function is immediately executed with a one parameter, which is a result of another IEFE. Hence

```
function() { console.log('1'); }()
```

is executed first, and immediately after that `window.onload` function expression. Then `console.log('2')` expression.

Great example why it's important not to forget semicolons at the end of the lines.

Comment: I'd also add that for the exact same reason lots of libraries, plugins etc which want to be bulletproof and are by them-selves ***Immediately Invoked Function Expressions*** `(function(){}());` they have a `;` as prefix like: `;(function(){}());` to prevent being destructed by sloppy code.